# Email Studio - Interactive Email - Data not stored in Data Extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, cloudpage, email-studio, interactive-email

So, I've setup an interactive email by selecting an cloud page (which has nothing but a thank you message), data extension, created attributes/ columns and then sent a test email.

From my gmail, I filled in the form, gave a rating, submitted and got redirected to thank you cloud page. Post that, I checked the DE - expecting my data to be present - but it wasn't. Any thoughts on what's wrong here please?

[image: Interactive email setup]

[image: DE with no data after interactive form is submitted]

Comment: In your data extension you have marked 'Id' as a primary key. Did you set the value for the ID as well in Interactive email content?

Comment: Yes... as suggested by @razor you can set the Hidden Field as `Id = %%_subscriberKey%%`

Comment: I've removed the primary key from DE and tried - still no change. My understanding is, the script behind the HTML inserts the record into DE isnt?

Comment: @MatheswaranKanagarajan I have tried it in my Org by removing the primary key. It is working fine. Please check if you have published the cloud page. Else you would need to check with SF support.

Comment: @MatheswaranKanagarajan Please find the answer [here] (https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/309932/interactive-email-forms-data-not-being-stored-in-data-extension-issue/309933#309933) .... Please confirm is this resolve your issue.