# Interactive Email Forms - Data NOT being stored in Data Extension Issue

Tags: marketing-cloud, interactive-email

Even I had faced a similar issue as stated [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/303525/email-studio-interactive-email-data-not-stored-in-data-extension)

After Creating and deleting many [Interactive Email Form Block](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_ceb_create_create_an_interactive_email_form.htm&type=5) and [Interactive Email Page](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_cp_create_an_interactive_email_page.htm&type=5) finally I was able to uncover the mystery!

Many of you may have or come up with this issue, while working on the new feature Interactive Email within Email studio and Web studio.

Please find the below tips to avoid this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Though all other features such as Interactive Form, and Landing page thank you message seems to work correctly. You may face ONLY the issue of the data NOT being STORED in Data Extension!

#### Here is the cause of the issue!!!

[image]

As you see in the above pic, every [Interactive Email Page](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_cp_create_an_interactive_email_page.htm&type=5) will have a *Email Form* block, this is where you have to select your Thank you message[any block as per your requirement].

Many of us have the habit of placing the block in the very first slot of the placeholder as below. But doing so may **display the landing page successfully, but will NOT store the data into Data Extension**.
[image]

So always select your block by clicking on *Email Form* and selecting your content block as below.

[image]

Also as suggested by [EasyE](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/66853/eazye) you can select the *No Content* option. And proceed with placing your block in first placeholder.
[image]

Comment: Yes the email form block needs to be configured, however, you can mark it to display No content, and add additional blocks to the page to show your submitted status

Comment: @EazyE thanks for your suggestion, I have updated my answer with your suggestion.